# multiple python versions after pip3 install

Tags: 18.04, python

I've spent a lot of time on the internet but did not found the information I need.
I've installed `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` from shell (I needed it for Pycharm venv - not important) but it seems that my python versions got messed up, there are new folders in lib, plus the disk size required was around 200mb which was odd.

I've since then uninstalled with `sudo apt-get remove python3-pip` + `sudo apt-get autoremove`. However, the folders in `usr/lib` still exist and if I try to install again it says ~80mb dependencies, meaning that some of the packages installed earlier still exist on my system.

The question - should I have installed pip3 for specific python version and why the change in python installations? Was there a better way to install pip3 on my system?

P.S. яну == Jan in date logs below.

```
/usr/bin$ ll -d python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 окт 25 14:11 python3 -> python3.6*
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4522328 окт 22 14:32 python3.6*
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4522328 окт 22 14:32 python3.6m*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 окт 25 14:11 python3m -> python3.6m*

/usr/lib$ ll -d python*
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 24576 ное 18 06:41 python2.7/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 юли 25  2018 python3/
drwxr-xr-x 30 root root 20480 яну 26 16:05 python3.6/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 яну 26 16:05 python3.7/

/usr/local/bin$ ll -d python*
ls: cannot access 'python*': No such file or directory
```